# Why am I getting a Javascript "if" failure?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error

```
alert(Tag);  // Tag shows it is set to 0 (ZERO) which is less than 10.

if ( Tag < 10) { alert("adding.."); Tag=Tag+10; }
else { alert("Fail"); }
alert(Tag);
```

// alert shows me "fail"
// and alert shows "0"

So, it says its zero, if statement DOES NOT show it less than 10,
and it remains zero.... What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Does `Tag` contain the number `0`, the string `'0'`, or the string `'ZERO'`?

Comment: where are you defining Tag initially?

Comment: you need to initialize (Tag = 0)  the Tag with 0 not "0".

Comment: even initializing with "0" wont alert "fail" in this case.. it would alert `adding` and then `010`

Answer (score 1):

This works when Tag is actually the number 0.

```
<script>
var Tag = 0;
alert(Tag);  // Tag shows it is set to 0 (ZERO) which is less than 10.

if ( Tag < 10) { alert("adding.."); Tag=Tag+10; }
else { alert("Fail"); }
alert(Tag);
</script>
```

Where do you assign Tag its value?

Comment: Was assigned in another external .js file which ran BEFORE this one, sorry. But the first alert(Tag); DID show it as being set to 0...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `Tag` first. I am also just incrementing `Tag` by 1. This can be changed if needed.

```
var Tag = 0;
if ( Tag < 10) { 
    alert("adding.."); 
    Tag++; 
}
else { 
    alert("Fail"); 
}
alert(Tag);
```

Comment: Tag was intended to be a Global variable.

Comment: @Ronk - you should _seriously_ avoid global variables. Google `javascript namespace pollution` for tons of discussions about it.

Comment: I have 60 different functions using the same variables, to pass them as arguments within scope would bog down slower tablets and phones.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/honixenopo/edit?js,console

I suspect tag is set to a string with the capital letter o as a type-o.